# How to do a time based internal interupt in Arduino code?

Tags: arduino, ide

I need to create an interrupt system that updates a PWM register every time interval x. However looking at the attachinterrupt() function, there doesn't seem to be a time based option, instead only a rising or falling edge detection input. Is it possible to make an interrupt with a recurring time based launch?

This is my code, I basically need to replace the for loop and microdelay() with a time based interrupt:

```
int D4 = 6;

byte arr[] = {0x06, 0x0C, 0x12, 0x18, 0x1E, 0x2A, 0x30, 0x36, 0x3C, 0x40, 0x3C, 0x36, 0x30, 0x2A, 0x1E, 0x18, 0x12, 0x0C, 0x06};

void setup() {
  CLKPR = (1<<CLKPCE)|(0<<CLKPS3)|(1<<CLKPS2)|(1<<CLKPS1)|(1<<CLKPS0);
  DDRC = (1<<DDC7)|(1<<DDC6);
  TCCR4A = (0<<COM4A1)|(1<<COM4A0)|(1<<PWM4A);
  TCCR4B = (0<<DTPS41)|(0<<DTPS40)|(0<<CS43)|(0<<CS42)|(0<<CS41)|(1<<CS40); 
  TCCR4D = (0<<WGM41)|(0<<WGM40);
  pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  OCR4C = 0x40;
 for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(arr) ; i++ ){

  OCR4A= arr[i];
  delayMicroseconds(100);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer interrupt that will interrupt the whole program at constant intervals, execute a block of code known as ISR (interrupt service routine) and then return to where it stopped in the rest of the program. Delays are usually bad as they stop the processor form doing anything useful. Adjust to your appropriate processor, it looks like an arduino Mega I guess, my added code will probably work but it's for the atmega 328 on the arduino Uno originally. Check the datasheets!

```
int D4 = 6,i = 0;

byte arr[] = {0x06, 0x0C, 0x12, 0x18, 0x1E, 0x2A, 0x30, 0x36, 0x3C, 0x40, 0x3C, 0x36, 0x30, 0x2A, 0x1E, 0x18, 0x12, 0x0C, 0x06};

void setup(){
    CLKPR = (1<<CLKPCE)|(0<<CLKPS3)|(1<<CLKPS2)|(1<<CLKPS1)|(1<<CLKPS0);
    DDRC = (1<<DDC7)|(1<<DDC6);
    TCCR4A = (0<<COM4A1)|(1<<COM4A0)|(1<<PWM4A);
    TCCR4B = (0<<DTPS41)|(0<<DTPS40)|(0<<CS43)|(0<<CS42)|(0<<CS41)|(1<<CS40); 
    TCCR4D = (0<<WGM41)|(0<<WGM40);
    pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);

    TCCR0A = (1<<WGM01); //setup timer 0 to clear its counter when it reaches the OCR0A
    TCCR0B = (1<<CS00)|(1<<CS01); //prescaler 1/64 to divide the 16 MHz clock by 64
    TIMSK0 = (1<<OCIE0A); //setup the timer to toggle the ISR flag A
    OCR0A = 25; //every 25 counts will represent 100 microseconds
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){ //This is the ISR routine itself, triggered by compare flag A of timer 0
  OCR4A = arr[i];
  ++i;
  if(i>sizeof(arr)) i = 0;
}

void loop(){
    OCR4C = 0x40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have been using Atmel controllers for a long long time, and are very new to Arduino.

Use the timer library described here.
https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1

Or you can implement a state space kind of program using micros. Example

```
long nextUpdateTime=micros();
loop(){
    if(nextUpdateTime<micros())
        return;
    nextUpdateTime=micros()+100; //Change 100 to what ever delay you want.
    // Write your required code here. This code will be called every 100 (Or whatever you set) us.
}
```

Then again, you could just use the analogWrite function to generate whatever pwm you are trying to generate. I am not certain what you are trying to do, but I believe knowledge of the function would help. here is the link
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

I hope this helps. Have a good day.